# Get single object by attribute in Algolia

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using the JavaScript API for Algolia and I'm trying to check for the existence of a single record. The API has clear documentation for how to do this where the ObjectID is known (`index.getObject`), but I need to check for the existence of a single result based on a different attribute:

```
post_id: 10050
objectID: 55345
```

In this case, the `post_id` is being set by the CMS and I want to query the Algolia index to check whether it exists (or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, this code seems to do the trick:

```
index.search({
    filters: 'post_id: 10050',
})
```

I'm not sure how performant this is, but it achieves the required result at the moment.